# OpenCV resize quality

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to resize a set of images using OpenCV. The resolution is correct, but the quality of the image degrades. However, if I do a manual resize through Apple Preview, the image quality is not affected. I am making all of these images smaller, rather than blowing them up. Here are two images comparing the quality. Please note the jagged spokes and jagged top tube of the bike:

Bad Resize:

[image: Bad OpenCV resize]

Good resize:

[image: Good Apple Preview resize]

Here is my code:

```
cv::Mat srcimg = cv::imread(src_filepath);
cv::Mat destimg = cv::imread(lowres_path);
cv::Size img_size = srcimg.size();
int img_width = img_size.width;
int img_height = img_size.height;
double percentage = 1000.0/(img_width);
double new_height = img_height * percentage;
cv::Size new_size = cv::Size(1000.0, new_height);
cv::resize(srcimg, destimg, new_size,0,0,CV_INTER_LANCZOS4);
cv::imwrite(lowres_path, destimg);
```

I've messed with the the interpolation but that seems to have no effect on the image.

Comment: Can you also post the original image?

Comment: @DanMašek: http://i.imgur.com/HYGvpSY.jpg

Comment: Acording to the docs, "To shrink an image, it will generally look best with CV_INTER_AREA interpolation". Did you try that? To me it looks a lot better than with Lanczos interpolation.

Comment: Yup, I tried it with that and it didn't have any significant effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All right, figured it out. I switched it back to CV_INTER_AREA and explicitly set the compression settings:

```
cv::resize(srcimg, destimg, new_size,0,0,CV_INTER_AREA);
vector<int> compression_params;
compression_params.push_back(CV_IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY);
compression_params.push_back(100);
cv::imwrite(lowres_path, destimg);
```

Comment: Oh, so it was JPEG that was messing things up? Might as well use a lossless codec like PNG if you want no loss in quality.